# PowerShell - Is there any way to rearrange columns in excel without Import-Excel

Tags: excel, powershell

I am trying to rearrange columns in an worksheet in excel. I am aware that Import-Excel or Import-CSV is the easier way but I do not have admin rights. If there is a workaround that would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code

```
$path = "C:\Users\file.xlsx"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($path)
$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.sheets.item("sheet1")

$column4 = $Worksheet.Columns.Item(4).value1
$column3 = $WorkSheet.Columns.Item(3).value1
$Column4.Cut()
$Column3.Insert()
```

Thank you

Comment: `Import-CSV` would not work for Excel files. `Import-Excel` is open source so you could look at the code on github to see how they import it. What's wrong with the code you have now? Please include the current behavior, what your expected behavior is, and any error messages you may be encountering.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move columns in xlsx file using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71462960/move-columns-in-xlsx-file-using-powershell)

Comment: Current behavior: getting an 'You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression' error. My expected behavior is for the code to be able to rearrange the selected column by copying and pasting it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `.value1` since it's just a value and not a reference to a column.

The following example should cut column A and paste it before column C.

```
$path = "G:\example.xlsm"
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$book = $excel.Workbooks.Open($path)
$sheet = $book.Sheets.Item("Sheet1")

$sheet.Columns("A:A").Cut()
$sheet.Columns("C:C").Insert()
$book.Save()
$excel.Quit()
```